# Creating View and Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Moving at snail's pace I started creating sample MVC app for printing website like vistaprint. I created a database with three tables, Client, JobType, Job.

1. Client table has ClientId, Name, Address
2. JobType is a look up table with types LetterPrint, CardPrint.
3. Job has clientId and jobtype id and fileformat.

Then created a EDMX file with all the table.

Now trying to create controller. How many controller do I need assuming that I will need to create a Client, and a Job. Job Type table will be updated using sql script?

I guess 1 controller for Client and Job each .

How many views I will need?

I think 3 for each of client and job. List, Create(update), Delete(readonly mode).

Am I going in right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It really depends on how you want the site to behave and look like.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Could you throw some light here and suggest some variations if you implemented it. Knowing another perspective will be very helpful for newbie  like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In suggestion that there be a some person (administrator or someone) who will create clients and create jobs asked by client I'll build such views:

1. Jobs:

   1. List of jobs. Can be filtered to show jobs asked by one client. One view, filtering happens in model/controller. There must be additional usually empty string about criteria of filtering. Of course, paging and another features should be enabled.
   2. Create job. Client id can be setuped before rendering view (when it was linked from some client). If not setuped, we must provide autocomplete search by client names. How it looks: admin types client name and in down, in some div with ajax list of clients loaded. So there must be one another action that returns filtered list of clients in JSON.
   3. Edit job
   4. Remove job.
2. Clients:

   1. List of clients. Paging, sorting, filtering. At each client must be link to jobs asked by client and link to create new job;
   2. Create client
   3. Edit client
   4. Remove client.

If client can login and ask for creating new job, there are must be additional views:

1. Register page
2. Login page

After login client must see only his jobs and their status and perhaps dunno about possibility (and have no such possibility) to reset filter. Perhaps, there can be special view for that, but I guess that there is need only in different filter setting in index action of jobs controller.

Special administrative actions must be marked with `AuthorizeAttribute`. Of course, there are a lot of possibilities to done it, but I think that this is nicest. Questions?

Comment: Thank you so much nsinreal for editing and answering my question.

Comment: Any other suggestion will be helpful, these will be probably foundation of my further progress in using MVC.

Comment: @MeProgramming That is good idea to do some task for learning MVC. But: that is simple task. There are no real problems in doing of this task, cuz 3 tables to small. The power of MVC grows with more and more entities and possible actions on them. With 3 tables there are no real need in mvc, it can be successfully done without patterns (of course, if we mean that "successfully" = no project growing in future). For learning I recommend you visit http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials and read some book about ASP.NET MVC and one another just about MVC pattern / patterns

Comment: @MeProgramming One possible task for you: try to write multiblog. There can be a lot of users, a lot of hubs (like thematic blog, but one article can be in many hubs), a lot of articles, a lot of tags, a lot of comments (level-divided, so each comment can have subcomment). Users can vote for article and comments, everyone can view user activity and view users who voted on specific article and comment. Articles can be added in favorites. After all add AJAX features.     Why this task? There are no real problems to do it, there are a lot of wasted time and a lot of views.

Comment: @MeProgramming or one another: site for creating polls and voting on them. With user activity and AJAX too

Comment: @nsireal Good idea about BlogSite..Another thing I wanted to mention that Register page
Login page  are given in samples i tried that. I read a little bit about Asyn and await also. Mine is about creating too many views, Create client, edit, delete. Now if I need to change a label like Adrressto  Full Address will I have to change at three places? Thanks

Comment: I will read a little bit more about not creating too many views.

Comment: @MeProgramming. In theory you can combine Create/Update Client in one view. There will be no real problems with that, MVC pattern about code reusing. You can push in ViewBag info about creating/editing/removing item and your view will show text labels based on that info. The problem that your code can be not clearly. But you can in code part of view initialize some variables that contains text like title = "Create new client"; title = "Edit client Vasya"; There no real problem if you will do that, you always can easily divide you globalclient view to many client views.

Comment: @MeProgramming another solution - making partial views. So, for Create and Edit you can can create partial view smth like _FillData, for Remove and Details you can create partial view like _ShowData. So you will have 6 views: Create, Edit, Remove, Details, _FillData, _ShowData. But only two last will have dependencies on all fields of Client class.

Comment: @MeProgramming  Anyway, this talking about views is subjective a lot. First what you must understand - sometimes there can be different principe of work of different actions. For example, there a lot of multiblog sites that provides ability to create poll. After creating post with poll, post must be editable, but poll no. Some another fields can be fixed too.

Comment: @MeProgramming Some fields can be edited only by admin guys - like user rights etc. In Remove you don't need to show all info about article, you need to show only title and few start lines from article. But in details you must show not only article, but comments to. There are no real patterns how to write your views, it's depends on your needs and on your model.

Comment: @MeProgramming There also two another ways in this situation. First: you can build your views automatically depending on your classes. You can use T4 (Text Template Transformation Toolkit) for this purposes, but that requires knowledge of reflection. In result after rewriting your class info you just rebuild project and views will be rewriten automatically. It's nice to use T4 with DataAnnotations attributes.

Comment: @MeProgramming and one another way - build single page app with use of javascript MVC frameworks like AngularJS or BackboneJS (more: http://www.infoq.com/research/top-javascript-mvc-frameworks), but that is bad idea for seo.

Comment: @MeProgramming and I have great advice for you: go to github.com, codeplex.com, google.com and find real opensource projects on ASP.NET MVC